# Help fixing Honeywell doorbell broken circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, connector, wire, repair

My Honeywell RCWL330A1000/N P4-Premium Portable Wireless Door Chime dropped to the floor the other day and has not worked since then. I unscrewed the casing an found a crack in the circuit board which I immediately glue back. But I think the connection is also broken but I am new to electrical diy and would appreciate some help in fixing this.

[image: Image of the crack]

[image: Picture of a spring which I think may be loose but not certain]

[image: Entire Circuit as seen with back of bell chime taken off]

[image: Closer image of board area with crack]

Answer (score 2):

If that's all the damage done, then all you have is 3 broken traces, in that first picture. Scrape some of the green solder mask off, tin and solder across the cracks. The electrical connection needs to be restored.

A youtube search for "how to fix broken trace" would provide a visual example.

Comment: Did you miss the part where I state that I am brand new to electrical DIY work? I am still reading through the last 2 chapters on Electricity and have never really connected a complex circuit, just the simple torch-light circuit with resistors in parallel, and then in series

Comment: None of which is needed to know here aside from how to solder.

Comment: Passerby told you exactly what to do step by step, just buy a soldering iron, google "how to solder" and follow the videos to fix those cracks in the copper. There may be a remote desktop software for IT engineers, but we can't remotely fix that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Passerby said, all you need to know to solve the problem is the basics of soldering. A helpful beginners guide can be found here:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Solder-on-PCB-traces/